# How do I simplify this long UIbutton code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I try to create 5 UIbutton (actually 12 but the code is to long to post so I cut to 5. It's all the same) and make its corner round and add drop shadow

but I think there is the better way to simplify this long code

please help. Thank you

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button5: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
       
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:1)
    button.layer.masksToBounds = false
    
    button2.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    button2.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    button2.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button2.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    button2.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:1)
    button2.layer.masksToBounds = false
    
    button3.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    button3.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    button3.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button3.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    button3.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:1)
    button3.layer.masksToBounds = false
    
    button4.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    button4.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    button4.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button4.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    button4.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:1)
    button4.layer.masksToBounds = false
    
    button5.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    button5.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    button5.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button5.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    button5.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:1)
    button5.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Comment: Why not just subclass UIButton?

Comment: I would like to learn how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function to do the repetitive work. Something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button5: UIButton!

//...
func configure(button: UIButton) {
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:1)
    button.layer.masksToBounds = false
}

[button, button2, button3, button4, button5].forEach { configure(button:$0) }
```

Comment: Work like magic! Thank you. Xcode also told me to add { configure(button: $0) } otherwise it got an error. My screen is much cleaner now :D

Comment: Glad I could help. Yeah, I missed the label on the button parameter. Now you should look up the Array.forEach function and practice using it until you "get it". It's quite useful.

Comment: Another enhancement you could use would be an `IBOutletCollection`
. That is a special form of IBOutlet that creates an array of every view object that you drag into it in Interface Builder. Then instead of having to say `[button, button2...]` you'd create an IBOutletCollection called buttons, control-drag all of your buttons into it, and then just say `buttons.forEach{<code>}`

Comment: wow, your method and description is easy to understand. Thx a lot. I will try using Array.forEach and IBOutletCollection for further understanding.

Answer (score 1):

it simple create one method and call it

```
[button,button2].forEach({self.createButton($0)})

func createButton(_ button: UIButton, radius: CGFloat = 35, shadowRadius: CGFloat = 5, shadowColor: UIColor = UIColor.black, shadowOpacity: Float = 0.5, shadowOffSet: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)){
    
    button.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    button.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
    button.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
    button.layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffSet
    button.layer.masksToBounds = false
    
}
```

Comment: Very nice use of default parameter values. This is another useful technique to learn. (voted)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use arrays

```
[button1,button2..].forEach { button in
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:1)
    button.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

or use methods, if you need to pass different params for different buttons

```
setupButton(button1)
setupButton(button2)

func setupButton(_ button: UIButton) {
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:1)
    button.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always subclass UIButton and create your own custom button:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 35
        layer.shadowRadius = 5
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:1)
        layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var button: CustomButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: CustomButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: CustomButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button4: CustomButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button5: CustomButton!
```

Comment: Note that your code won't work if the button is created in a storyboard or XIB. (In those cases the `init(coder:)` method gets called. I usually create a shared `setup()` method that I call from both `init(frame:)` and `init(coder:)`. That way I can invoke my view objects either in code or from a Storyboard and get the same behavior (and don't have to maintain the same setup code in 2 places.)

Comment: @DuncanC You're 100% right, I do most of my views programmatically, so just a small oversight out of habit.  I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: thx you for another perspective. I just begin to code and this is too advance for me right now XD

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try this in swift 5.3 using Variadic Parameters

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button5: UIButton!

//...
func configure(buttons: UIButton...) {
    for button in buttons {
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 35
        button.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:0, height:1)
        button.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
}
configure(button, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5)
```